# StoryBoard - View Controllers how to switch?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have my button here, at the end of this function i want to switch to another view controller. However I cannot figure out how to switch it, i am only working for an iphone version of the app.

```
- (IBAction)loginMe:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.111:8888/api.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *requester = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=account&username=%@&password=%@",self.username.text,self.password.text];
    NSData *requestBody = [requester dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if([responseString isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        self.data.text = @"Username or password incorrect";
    }
    else
    {
        NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

        NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [ud setInteger:1 forKey:@"isLoggedin"];
        [ud setObject:[publicTimeline objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"userid"];
        [ud setObject:[publicTimeline objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"username"];
        [ud setObject:[publicTimeline objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"loginstr"];
        [ud synchronize];
        [self animateLoginBox];
        self.data.text = responseString;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried control dragging from the button to the new view controller and give it a modal segue? I assume you are using storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are your view controllers embedded in a navigation controller? if so;

import that view controllers .h into the top of the current view controller.
Then in storyboard create a storyboard id for that view controller. Then in the method which moves to the new view controller try this:

```
 YourNewViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryboardID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

But if it is not embedded in a navigation controller try this:

```
YourNewViewController *newVC = [[YourNewViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not using a navigation controller. However the presetnModalViewController says its deprecated. Any other ideas?

Comment: try ,     [self presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @NicholasYoung, if you type the name of a depreciated method into the Documentation search, and click on that method (with a red line through it) it will tell you what the replacement method is.

Comment: That didnt work either but i figured it out: